# How to use Close a dynamic Popup with python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

Im trying to close this popup but i cant,
i have tried using `find.element.by.xpath()` 
with all the different possibilities i guess,
tried using `switch_to _alert().dismiss()`  but nothing seems to help
Any help is much appreciated,
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems **NOT** an **Alert**. It is just another element on webpage.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following css selector

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div#dismiss-button"))).click()
```

you need to import below libarries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Note: if you get timeout error then please check if the element is under `iframe`. If so you need to switch to `iframe` in order to interact the button element.